# BodyInserters.fromObject is deprecated, what is the alternative?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

Helllo.
I am trying to use Spring webclient to send post requests and fill the body with an object. But I receive the following " 'fromObject(T)' is deprecate".
What is the alternative then ?

```
WebClient.post()
            .uri("example.com")
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(newObject);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The javadoc clearly says to use `fromValue`.

```
public static <T> BodyInserter<T,ReactiveHttpOutputMessage> fromValue(T body)
```

Inserter to write the given value.
Alternatively, consider using the bodyValue(Object) shortcuts on WebClient and ServerResponse.

**Type Parameters:**

`T` - the type of the body

**Parameters:**
`body` - the value to write

**Returns:**

the inserter to write a single value

**Throws:**

`IllegalArgumentException` - if body is a Publisher or an instance of a type supported by `ReactiveAdapterRegistry.getSharedInstance()`, for which `fromPublisher(Publisher, Class)` or `fromProducer(Object, Class)` should be used.

Comment: Thank you So much. Changing to
 WebClient.post()
            .uri("example.com")
            .body(.fromValue(<T> object); 
did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I use this way, and it worked

ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
.body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(Mono.just("Hello World!"),String.class));